# Java: transfering elements from one ArrayList to another ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

If I have a list of Products(an inventory):

```
public List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
```

After a customer selects a given product for purchase, can I/how do I remove the product from productList(my inventory) and place it in another list (the customer's shoppingCart)?  From here, if the customer decides he/she would not like to purchase the product (proceed to checkout) can I/how do I remove this product from shoppingCart & return it to productList?

Comment: Have you looked at the List API in the Java Docs? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `List.remove(Product)` and `List.add(Product)` methods.

Just make sure that the `equals` method in `Product` class is implemented properly and because the `remove()` method removes the element from list if equals method returns true.

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
public List<Product> shoppingCart = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

Customer selects the product

```
shoppingCart.add(p); //p is the product object
```

Check if the customer checks out

```
 boolean customerChecksOut = true;

 if(customerChecksOut)
 customerChecksOut(p);
 else
 customerDropsTheProduct(p);

 void customerChecksOut(Product p){
 productList.remove(p);
 }

 void customerDropsTheProduct(p)
 {
 shoppingCart.remove(p);
 }
```

You also need to override the equals & hashcode method in your product class.